# How can I draw an ellipse on the mouse click event within a specific area in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

Right now I am drawing an ellipse on click event. But that is not restricted to the arc. Please run the code for clear understanding. Please help me to restrict the drawing of the ellipse inside the arc area.

**asdf.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'designerjOXOCu.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.14.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################

from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

**Main.py**

```
import sys
import platform
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QPropertyAnimation, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt, QEvent)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen, QPainterPath

from asdf import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    hourColor = QColor(127, 0, 127)
    minuteColor = QColor(0, 127, 127, 191)

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        def moveWindow(e):
            # Detect if the window is  normal size
            # ###############################################  
            
            if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:  
                #Move window 
                self.move(self.pos() + e.globalPos() - self.clickPosition)
                self.clickPosition = e.globalPos()
                e.accept()
        
        #self.ui.label_2.mouseMoveEvent = moveWindow

        # WIDGET TO MOVE
    
    # def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    #     # ###############################################
    #     # Get the current position of the mouse
    #     self.clickPosition = event.globalPos()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.target_x_pos = event.x()
        self.clickPosition = event.globalPos()
        self.target_y_pos = event.y()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        #side = min(self.width(), self.height())

        q = QPainter()
        q.begin(self)
        
        q.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        #q.translate(self.width()/2 , self.height()/2 )
        #q.scale(side / 200.0, side / 200.0)
        
        #q.drawLine(20, 50, 40, 100)

        # q.setPen(QPen(Qt.cyan))

        # for k in range(180):
        #     if ((k % 10) != 0):
        #         q.drawLine(92, 0, 96, 0)
        #     q.rotate(-1.0)

        # q.setPen(QPen(Qt.blue))

        # for i in range(181):
        #     if (i == 180) or ((i % 10) == 0):
        #         q.drawLine(88, 0, 96, 0)
        #     q.rotate(1.0)

        # #q.rotate(-1)

        q.setPen(QPen(Qt.green,  8, Qt.DashLine))
        q.setBrush(QBrush(QColor('#000000')))
        q.drawArc(100, 100, 500, 500, 0 * 16, 180 * 16)

        q.setPen(QPen(Qt.blue))
        q.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue)

        q.drawEllipse(self.target_x_pos,self.target_y_pos, 5, 5)

        q.end()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app= QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: We need `asdf` to run your code. What is it? The module that is installable with `pip3 install asdf` doesn't seem to contain an `Ui_MainWindow`.

Comment: I have added the "asdf.py" code.

Comment: Why have you removed the screenshots?

Comment: At the moment, you don't call your paintEvent method. If you want to draw the ellipse on a mouse click, perhaps you should call this method at the end of the mousePress method.

Comment: @scotty3785 that's wrong. `paintEvent` is called by the framework, as it's called by a drawing request from the OS.

Comment: @musicamante I stand corrected. The OP still needs to call a function to draw the ellipse when the user clicks.

Comment: That automatically happens (as soon as the event queue of the Qt framework allows it) after calling `self.update()`. With the given code, the painting works, that's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @musicamante Please answer my question.

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you please tell me, how can I use `.sigMouseClicked` and get coordinates in some variable. As you showed in this link. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833107/mouse-coordinates-of-pytqt-graph-line)